# .htaccess Url Rewrite Remove Query-String Keys

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, url-rewriting

I have a set of urls like...

```
www.example.com/page/1/name/abc
www.example.com/city/la/name/abc
www.example.com/page/1/name/abc/city/la
www.example.com/page/1/
```

And want to convert them as..

```
www.example.com/1/abc
www.example.com/la/abc
www.example.com/1/abc/la
www.example.com/1/
```

Basically i want to hide keys from query string.

How to do this? Any Help?

**Edit**

I have different keys for every page and there are about 25 keys per page.

Comment: This is somewhat unclear.  Is the issue that you have redirects coming from your controllers that look like the first set of URLs, and want the browser to only display the second list of URLs?  If so, is there any reason you would not want to do this with Apache and mod_rewrite?

Comment: Yes you are getting it right. And i didn't say that i don't want to do this with Apache and mod_rewrite.

Comment: From your example URL's this is almost impossible, how would you know what value comes from what key? if you remove the keys, they are gone. you would need a pattern to resolve every value again

Comment: @martin.. is it possible to do or not?

Comment: I haven't tested it myself, but I think @mabarroso below has the right starting point... I think you should change the question to be clear that you are looking for a solution to rewrite the URLs, not just interpret them on the backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Zend_Controller_Router_Route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard.variable-requirements) and/or [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex) and define the routes

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':key/:city_name',
    array(
        'controller' => 'somecontroller',
        'action'     => 'pageAction'
    ),
    array('key' => '^\d+$')
);
$router->addRoute('page', $route); // www.example.com/1/abc

$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':key/:city_name',
    array(
        'controller' => 'somecontroller',
        'action'     => 'cityAction'
    ),
    array('key' => '^\d+\w+$') // www.example.com/1a/abc
);
$router->addRoute('city', $route);
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this wouldn't solve his issue which is that he wants to actually rewrite the URLs first... this WOULD however provide the solution to interpret the re-written URLs.

Answer (score 2):

Front controller is a design pattern which maps uri through single point and Zend is using front controller pattern. This maping can be change at bootstrap.php. I googled and found [this questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402088/zend-url-parameter-hide-key-and-show-value)n which is pretty similar.

Answer (score 2):

I would maintain the default `.htaccess` that routes all requests (except for front-end resources like img, css, js, etc) to `index.php`. Then add [routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html) at bootstrap to handle your redirect.

For the existing urls that you want to change to new urls, I'd create a `RedirectController` with actions that redirect - really redirect, with an HTTP 301 code, not just perform the same action - to your desired urls.

There is a valid argument against implementing redirects down at app-level via routes vs handling it up `.htaccess`: it will be less performant since an entire bootstrap/dispatch cycle is required to make the redirect happen. This is a fair argument, but I find it clearer to have all my routing information in a single place, not split across both `.htaccess` and my app-level routes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    #1 www.example.com/1/abc to www.example.com/page/1/name/abc (/number/string)
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ /page/$1/name/$2 [L,QSA]

    #2 www.example.com/la/abc to www.example.com/city/la/name/abc (/string/string)
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /city/$1/name/$2 [L,QSA]

    #3 www.example.com/1/abc/la to www.example.com/page/1/name/abc/city/la (/number/string/string)
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /page/$1/name/$2/city/$3 [L,QSA]

    #4 www.example.com/1/ to www.example.com/page/1/ (/number/)
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ /page/$1/ [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The rules order is very important. Do not change. The rule 1 must be always before the rule 2. The rule 4 must be always the last. The order is from the most especific to the most generic rule. The rule 3 could be in any position, but before the rule 4.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to uniform your url. Then it will be easier to work with.
   Here is a practical example.

**.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Remove trailing '/' from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+[^/])/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Convert url to ?q=/US/en/0001
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=%1 [NS,L]

# Input: /US/en/0001
# Output print_r($_GET);
# Array
# (
#    [country] => US
#    [locale] => en
#    [pid] => 0001
# )
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=/([A-Z]{2})/([a-z]{2})/([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?country=%1&locale=%2&pid=%3 [NS,L]

# Input: /US/en
# Output print_r($_GET);
# Array
# (
#    [country] => US
#    [locale] => en
# )
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=/([A-Z]{2})/([a-z]{2})$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?country=%1&locale=%2 [NS,L]

# Input: /US
# Output print_r($_GET);
# Array
# (
#    [country] => US
# )
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=/([A-Z]{2})$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?country=%1 [NS,L]
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    print_r($_GET);
?>
```